# SharePoint Documents Libraries copy into Azure Blob Storage

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, migration, azure

- I have a requirement to copy all SharePoint Document libraries into Azure Solutions.
  like copy into Azure Storage account/ CosmosDB, etc.,

I request anyone to suggest any solution or tool to copy all SharePoint Documents into Azure Blob Storage Account.

Answer (score 0):

- This PowerShell script shows how to download and sync documents in a SharePoint Document Library into an Azure Storage Container using CLI for Microsoft 365 and Azure CLI commands.

  ```
   $spolHostName = "https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com"
   $spolSiteRelativeUrl = "/sites/site-name"
   $spolDocLibTitle = "document-library-title"
   $azStorageAccountKey = "*****************"
   $azStorageAccountName = "azure-storage-account-name"
   $azStorageContainerName = "azure-storage-container-name"
   $localBaseFolderName = "local-base-folder-name"

   $localFileDownloadFolderPath = $PSScriptRoot
   $spolSiteUrl = $spolHostName + $spolSiteRelativeUrl

   $spolLibItems = m365 spo listitem list --webUrl $spolSiteUrl --title 
   $spolDocLibTitle --fields 'FileRef,FileLeafRef' --filter "FSObjType eq 0" -o json | ConvertFrom-Json

   if ($spolLibItems.Count -gt 0) {
     ForEach ($spolLibItem in $spolLibItems) {
       $spolLibFileRelativeUrl = $spolLibItem.FileRef
       $spolFileName = $spolLibItem.FileLeafRef

       $spolLibFolderRelativeUrl = $spolLibFileRelativeUrl.Substring(0, $spolLibFileRelativeUrl.lastIndexOf('/'))

   $localDownloadFolderPath = Join-Path $localFileDownloadFolderPath $localBaseFolderName $spolLibFolderRelativeUrl

   If (!(test-path $localDownloadFolderPath)) {
     $message = "Target local folder $localDownloadFolderPath not exist"
     Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Yellow

     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $localDownloadFolderPath | Out-Null

     $message = "Created target local folder at $localDownloadFolderPath"
     Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Green
   }
   else {
     $message = "Target local folder exist at $localDownloadFolderPath"
     Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Blue
   }

   $localFilePath = Join-Path $localDownloadFolderPath $spolFileName

   $message = "Processing SharePoint file $spolFileName"
   Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Green

   m365 spo file get --webUrl $spolSiteUrl --url $spolLibFileRelativeUrl --asFile --path $localFilePath

   $message = "Downloaded SharePoint file at $localFilePath"
   Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Green
     }

     $localFolderToSync = Join-Path $localFileDownloadFolderPath 
   $localBaseFolderName
     az storage blob sync --account-key $azStorageAccountKey --account-name $azStorageAccountName -c $azStorageContainerName -s $localFolderToSync --only-show-errors | Out-Null

     $message = "Syncing local folder $localFolderToSync with Azure Storage Container $azStorageContainerName is completed"
     Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Green
   }
   else {
     Write-Host "No files in $spolDocLibTitle library" -ForegroundColor Yellow
   }
  ```
- Copy files from SharePoint to Azure Blob storage using Microsoft Flow: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copy-files-from-sharepoint-to-an-azure-blob-storage-using-microsoft-flow/