# How to overcome the 100mb buffer file size error

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I made a Power Automate that copies a file from a SharePoint document library to an Azure Blob storage.

[image]

This works fine, until I hit a file bigger than 100mb. Then I get this message:
[image]

"Http request failed as there is an error: 'Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600.'."

Some actions allow to turn on chunking in their settings, but this is not one of those. I've tried using a REST call action to get the file content, but the same error pops up.

Is there any way around this issue? And if not, what is a good alternative, or best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that there is no way could increase the maximum buffer size, it has reached the limits of message size 100MB (104857600bytes = 100 MB).

You could refer to this document:

[Limits and configuration - Power Automate | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config#message-size)

Maybe you can use the power shell to copy a file from a SharePoint document library to an Azure Blob storage.
Here is the link: [SharePoint Documents Libraries copy into Azure Blob Storage](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299273/sharepoint-documents-libraries-copy-into-azure-blob-storage)